# Boston Data Set, Multiple Filters based on values

Tags: r, filter, subset, multiple-columns, data-extraction

I am a beginner. I was working with the Boston data set in the MASS package. I wanted to apply a filter to obtain the records where value of variable "chas" is 1 / TRUE and value of variable "age" is greater than 50.0

I tried :

```
> boston2<-subset(Boston, chas>0, age>50.0)
> boston2
```

The result I got was: 
data frame with 0 columns and 35 rows

However, I wanted all the records where chas is true and age is greater than 50 in a data frame.

What are the alternate methods I can use? And how can I extend the filtering to 3 / 4 / any number of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect your different criteria using the various logical operators:

```
subset(Boston, chas > 0 & age > 50.0)
```

Read `?Logic` to learn more.

The documentation for `subset` specifies that the second argument, `subset`, must be a single logical expression. When you separate them with commas, R interprets them as entirely different arguments, not as a single expression.

Your attempt is equivalent to:

```
subset(Boston, subset = chas > 0, select = age > 50.0)
```

so you get "all rows but no columns".

Comment: Got it. I will study all logical operators to be used within functions. Thanks! I also read that subsetting may not be the best way and using [ or [[ is a better idea, specially when writing programs. Is there an alternate approach that can be used to solving this?